# Perl: How to get keys on key "keys on reference is experimental"

Tags: perl

I am looking for a solution to Perl's warning

"keys on reference is experimental at"

I get this from code like this:

```
foreach my $f (keys($normal{$nuc}{$e})) {#x, y, and z
```

I found something similar on StackOverflow here:

[Perl throws "keys on reference is experimental"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613951/perl-throws-keys-on-reference-is-experimental)

but I don't see how I can apply it in my situation.

How can I get the keys to multiple keyed hashes without throwing this error?

Comment: Trivia: This experimental behaviour has been removed from 5.24. Doing `keys($ref)` in 5.24+ will fail as it did before the experiment began.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
keys %{$normal{$nuc}{$e}}
```

E.g. dereference it first.

If you had a reference to start off with, you don't need `{}` E.g.:

```
my $ref = $normal{$nuc}{$e};
print keys %$ref;
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `$normal{$nuc}{$e}` is a hash *reference*, and `keys` will officially only accept a hash. The solution is simple—you must *dereference* the reference—and you can get around this by writing

```
for my $f ( keys %{ $normal{$nuc}{$e} } ) { ... }
```

but it may be wiser to extract the hash reference into an intermediate variable. This will make your code much clearer, like so

```
my $hr = $normal{$nuc}{$e};

for my $f ( keys %$hr ) { ... }
```

I would encourage you to write more meaningful variable names. `$f` and `$e` may tell you a lot while you're writing it, but it is sure to cause others problems, and it may even come back to hit you a year or two down the line

Likewise, I am sure that there is a better identifier than `$hr`, but I don't know the *meaning* of the various levels of your data structure so I couldn't do any better. Please call it something that's relevant to the data that it points to

Comment: thanks, you're completely correct. I wrote this script more than a year ago, came back to it, and had forgotten what many of the variables mean.  In reading other people's python scripts, I have come across the problem of poor identifiers.  In a lot of cases, if you know what the hash key can be, you should use a list of them in foreach instead, it makes the code much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
keys $hash_ref
```

is the reason for the warning keys on references is experimental

Solution:

```
keys %{ $hash_ref }
```

Reference:

https://www.perl.com/pub/2005/07/14/bestpractices.html/